# what does "wire" mean for pb of binary wire format?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am not sure if the question is about English or about tech.
Does the "wire" mean something in technical terms?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's intended to be understood as "the format of the data as it travels on the wire (i.e. in a network)". In reality, it's just "the binary protobuf format" - it doesn't make any difference whether the proto message is being saved to disk, sent across a network, or just generated in memory.

This is in comparison with:

- "The protobuf text format" (which isn't very clearly documented as far as I can remember; it's mostly used internally at Google)
- "[The protobuf JSON format](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json)"
- Any in-memory representation